# Where is the asset folder for Android [JavaFxPorts]

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

I used Gluon plugin for Netbeans in developing Javafx Apps to be ported in Android, I want to add some files in the asset folder in Android but I couldn't find it? Where to place the **Asset Files**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gluon plugin creates a [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) project to which the jfxmobile plugin is applied. Documentation on the jfxmobile plugin for Gradle can be found here: http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_getting_started

The default android assets directory is `src/android/assets`, but can be changed by specifying the `assetsDirectory` property in your build.gradle file:

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        assetsDirectory = 'src/android/my_assets_dir'
    }
}
```